# To use a participle or an infinitive? That's the question

Tags: infinitives, participles

Would native speakers use "to harm" in this one? Thanks.

> The elephant king agreed. He ordered that the elephants stop stepping on a single mouse. From then on, the elephants paid attention and lifted their huge legs carefully, never ___ their tiny friends.

1. harm
2. harmed
3. harming
4. to harm

Comment: Either *harming* or *to harm* is grammatical. The others are not.

Comment: I'd use *harming* or *to harm*.

Comment: IMO, *to harm* is the more likely usage here. It has that fairy-tale feel to it, suggestive of a behavior that would last through the ages.

Comment: @Robusto , Thanks. So, if I split the sentence into two, do both of the following work? 1.they were never to harm their tiny friends.
2.they would never harm their tiny friends.

Answer (score 3):

You have two possibilities, both grammatical, but with different meanings

1. "harming" means that they did not, in fact, harm the mice
2. "to harm" means that they took the care for the purpose of refraining from the harm.

Comment: _Harming_ in no way means that they did not harm the mice. The context makes clear that the elephants had already harmed mice previously _...ordered that the elephants stop stepping on a single mouse..._ . Furthermore, this part is qualified by _from then on_ so the net effect is: _never harming their tiny friends from then on_. The best we could say is that from that point on, no more mice were harmed.

Comment: Because "harming" is a modifying clause, it means that the action it is modifying did not harm the mice, not that they never harmed them.

Comment: The gerund-participial clause is an adjunct to the main clause. It shows the resultant situation: B because of A. There is an overlap between the two where the _to_-infinitival could show purpose, but could also show a resultant situation. This is why this clause needs _again_ in it to make clear that though they did harm the mice before, they now _paid attention and lifted their huge legs carefully_ with the result that _they never again harmed their tiny friends_. Note that this wouldn't make sense without _again_ or _anymore_ or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Either *harming* or *to harm* would work, but the sentence really needs an *again* at the end since they already harmed them before.

Comment: "again" would be redundant here since "never" is already qualified by "from then on"

Comment: @EspeciallyLime: Then I guess you think the anti-Holocaust rallying cry "Never Again!" could make do with only one of those words?

Comment: @Robusto No, of course not. If you read the whole of my comment, it should obviously only imply that *if* the rallying cry had been "From now on, never again!" *then* it could have been trimmed down a bit. But I guess whoever came up with it already realised that.

Answer (score 0):

I think harming is the intended answer. "Never harming..." is a grammatically correct and idiomatic way to express that (from then on) they never harmed the mice.

"Never to harm...", while it might technically be grammatical, is not so idiomatic; I don't recall ever hearing that construction (and am a native speaker). If I intended this meaning, I would write "in order never to harm..." or something similar.

In fact, the passage is slightly modified from a story available [here](https://healingstory.org/the-mice-and-the-elephant/?doing_wp_cron=1589283030.1835880279541015625000), and "never harming" is the original version.